# Transpose data frames inside a list of lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of lists containing multiple data frames.  I would like to transpose the data frames and leave the lists structured as is.

The data is setup in this format (from:John McDonnell):

```
parent <- list(
  a = list(
    foo = data.frame(first = c(1, 2, 3), second = c(4, 5, 6)),
    bar = data.frame(first = c(1, 2, 3), second = c(4, 5, 6)),
    puppy = data.frame(first = c(1, 2, 3), second = c(4, 5, 6))
  ),
  b = list(
    foo = data.frame(first = c(1, 2, 3), second = c(4, 5, 6)),
    bar = data.frame(first = c(1, 2, 3), second = c(4, 5, 6)),
    puppy = data.frame(first = c(1, 2, 3), second = c(4, 5, 6))
  )
)
```

This works when a single list of data frames is used, but not for a list of lists:

```
a_tran <- lapply(a, function(x) {
  t(x)
})
```

Any thoughts on how to modify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `modify_depth` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
modify_depth(.x = parent, .depth = 2, .f = ~ as.data.frame(t(.)))
#$a
#$a$foo
#       V1 V2 V3
#first   1  2  3
#second  4  5  6

#$a$bar
#       V1 V2 V3
#first   1  2  3
#second  4  5  6

#$a$puppy
#       V1 V2 V3
#first   1  2  3
#second  4  5  6


#$b
# ...
```

---

A `base R` option that @hrbrmstr initially posted in a comment would be

```
lapply(parent, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) as.data.frame(t(y))))
```

Comment: You need to re-convert them to data frames… _" would like to transpose the data frames"_ suggests the OP wants data frames back

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thanks. Edited.

Comment: That will definitely do it! For some reason though my actual data returns:Error in t.default(.) : argument is not a matrix.  Thanks!